# How to conditionally change style url in angular component ? is it possible?

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I have two css file for arbaic layout and english layout , so I want to conditionally change the styleurl in component . is possible or not 
?

Comment: can't... but can use ngClass at the very top to make theme type changes; kinda like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53077314

Comment: what you tried so far? feel free to share your code so we will get batter idea what want wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot put a condition in the styleUrls attribute of the component, but instead, you can use something like that:

```
.some-class {
  // your css style
}

//  arabic css  overrides
._ar {
   .some-class {
    direction: rtl;
   }
}



<div class="parent" [class._ar]="your_condition">
    <textarea class="some-class">
    </textarea>
</div>
```