# Check if Object is Empty using typescript generic

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I am new to typescript and in a learning phase. I am trying to create a generic to enforce the following condition

Consider I have a empty object

```
const data = {}
```

I need to create a generic which will check the following conditions

Check if its an object if yes, then check if there is any data inside it , else return false

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this utility to check whether object type is empty or not:

```js
// credits goes to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23182#issuecomment-379091887
type IsEmptyObject<Obj extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>> =
    [keyof Obj] extends [never] ? true : false

type Test = IsEmptyObject<{}> // true

type Test2 = IsEmptyObject<{ age: 42 }> // false
```

If `Obj` does not have any keys then `keyof Obj` returns `never`.

Our goal is to check whether it returns `never` or not.

In order to check it, we need to stop [distributivity](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).

If `keyof Obj` returns `never` then our conditional type `IsEmptyObject` returns `true`.

If you want to use it in a function, consider this example:

```js
type IsEmptyObject<Obj extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>> =
    [keyof Obj] extends [never] ? true : false

function isEmpty<Obj extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>>(obj: Obj): IsEmptyObject<Obj>
function isEmpty<Obj extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>>(obj: Obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).length === 0
}

const result = isEmpty({}) // true
const result2 = isEmpty({ age: 42 }) // false
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAkgZwKIFsLgPICMBWUDGIAPNjjFAB4hQB2AJgjAEoED2ATnUQAruvTtwAaShgANDACuNANY1WAdxoA%20ZTAC8wGNpgBtGaNYAzGKQC65KrQZ6aUAG5R2FgPwwQ7SbABcMIwEMAGwQoYGAjaUIAS1YaGCjkNHASXEtqekYWfA4uXn4nYVEJaTlFFWUAClZcX1IASl9EVHQwUgJiUmVwyJAYuITm5NI060y2Th4%20AULxKVl5JVUqmtNcOpgAby0ddigQSXY4tsIAOgMwBGWcOpPA2gBzEAALDXV1GAAGYABfMOyaBAgGC7BCSQJA94DJJgCobb7rAD0CPcnlC-0BwKgoPBACYNPFEi1YTB-PcoL4ACx4%20EwJF%20IIhIA)

Also you need to be aware that it works only with literal types.

If you want to make it work with higher order function and I bet you want, please consider this example:

```js
type IsEmptyObject<Obj extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>, Keys = keyof Obj> =
    PropertyKey extends Keys ? boolean : [keyof Obj] extends [never] ? true : false

function isEmpty<Obj extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>>(obj: Obj): IsEmptyObject<Obj>
function isEmpty<Obj extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>>(obj: Obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).length === 0
}

const higherOrderFunction = (obj: Record<PropertyKey, unknown>) => {
    const test = isEmpty(obj) // boolean

    return test
}

const result3 = higherOrderFunction({ age: 2 }) // boolean
```

If `isEmpty` is unable to infer literal type, it will return `boolean` by the default, since you never know what you can get in higher order function.

If you infer `obj` argument in `higherOrderFunction`, `isEmpty` in turn will be able to infer argument too.

```js
const higherOrderFunction = <T extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>>(obj: T) => {
    const test = isEmpty(obj) // IsEmptyObject<T, keyof T>

    return test
}

const result3 = higherOrderFunction({ age: 2 }) // false
const result4 = higherOrderFunction({ }) // true
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgzgUQLZlAeQEYCsIGNgA8mWUEAHsBAHYAmcUASngPYBONBACq85K6AGkIIADRQArlQDWVZgHcqAPjFCQ9ALxQpw5gDMoxRVHUAoKOajdeEfiFWkK1OlFX0A-FAzNmAGwgBDKigALigAbW0QPQNsAF0HSlp6MKoIADcbeI9gVnFoUN1-HzgIExNdSXwAS2YgqsQUUCJsBKd6Jlw2Dis%20QWExSRl5JUUACmZsUOIASlD4ZFQQYjxCQ3LK4Bq6hsXmknJE5w6urh5eu36JaVkFRTGJrCnsaagAbzMLVghgcVYg5fwADpInBxs9AX4qABzYAAC2M6k0AAYTABfMqdKhwYBQWFVKGwmxodg2ABiGy2xigBAAKq0kowWOxTtZbKoBtdhncwY8oDSXuojO8LFBMdioJRxZp6gtQDyXgB6BWwHbobArWliSLRGmKMoir4-P4SiDYtEY2rir5wcQ%20YAAZipeIJRJJrHJVGqtVGryg-ihEFCACYoKjFcrCsVSmKcdbbcAACxO-GE1jEmhkine31hqBKiW5CBAA)

I'm not sure what you mean:  `then check if there is any data inside it`.

**Question:**

Let's say we have this object: `{age: undefined}`. Do you consider it with data or not ?

Answer (score -2):

```js
const data = {};
console.log("Check if object is empty", Object.keys(data).length == 0);
console.log("Check if it is object", typeof data === "object");
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const emptyObject = (data:Object) => {
    if(typeof data == "object"){
        if(Object.keys(data).length == 0){
            console.log("Empty Object");
            return true;
        }
        else{
            console.log("Not Empty Object");
        }
    }
    else{
        console.log("Not an Object");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here are some examples and the logs generated.

**EXAMPLES**

```
console.log(emptyObject({}));
console.log(emptyObject("acd"));
console.log(emptyObject({
    "acd": 1
}));
```

**LOGS**

```
[LOG]: "Empty Object" 
[LOG]: true 
[LOG]: "Not an Object" 
[LOG]: false 
[LOG]: "Not Empty Object" 
[LOG]: false
```