# Omit never types in typescript

Tags: typescript

Is it possible somehow to omit all `never` types from a type in typescript? I have a type that takes two other types, and based on values, generates a third type, and sets all incorrectly or differently valued elements to never:

```
type MapForeignKeys<TExpandMap extends expandMap, TForeignKeys> = {
    [Prop in keyof TExpandMap]: 
        TExpandMap[Prop] extends { association: 'belongsTo', instance: BaseModel, foreignKey: any } 
        ? TExpandMap[Prop]['instance']['_creationAttributes'] | TExpandMap[Prop]['instance'] | TForeignKeys[TExpandMap[Prop]['foreignKey']] 
        : never 
                       
}
```

When I try to use this type, the output contains properties that should be set to `never`, instead of omitting those types from the type definition, thus this becomes unusable.

A simple example that describes my problem can be found in [this playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAhlC8UDeAoK7YC4oGdgCcBLAOwHMUBfFFUSKAIwWTQ3u2IgDcJ9LrboMRojgAyBgG5qAYwD2xPFGAQ82IU1QYsUAOTK8OyhKgB6E1ACSUfBGkRC3WFDkBbMABsYJYA1swArjjQAET0wVCEOFDEsj5g+LKchAAmEMnUKHIKPvrAasLMWjDYeirAOgA0LOhsUP7EqQBmJGlGpuZWNnYOgs6ybp7evtIBQVCh4TgAFrL+7sm+0Vw8QA)

**EDIT:** A new link with some [reproductible example of the problem](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gEwgGygXigQwHYigenygQFcBbMkAKCogA8w4AnYKUSKesHBAJROQQAPABV4SVPWARsCAM6xEKAHzooAbypRtUAJbY5wHAGMIALihilqAD6XxKANoBdADRadmOXLjHdmYF04bAsAcgAjFGCAczkROFCoO1CACy8YHBBQ9x09bGNkEiQLTJydADNmCF1o7ABpCBAAfhLcKgBfGnZoLh4MsDVNXMcAa0aLQyZ9aOcLXtl+QSFM5Q6u8Gh+gDEqmvrGuVEAUQY+zAGpGXlOU9l+10sdpmrahpA5VQwhnUcABSY4AN9FAxiA4OVLCduHdzrMoB5ctoRFCzmA-gCwM4btJZAp1FhvL5-IFgmFIsgYnEEg99IYTOZFBIHpVnns3q08O14YidE1IbcEP10YDnI5QrSjPkIKEsXYRE8Xvt3o5kQKhf8RWKWYq3jKsQjERZsBAAG4QJg8y1W+GdKjdKAANUwhQghxEn0so0a4MsznWHAA8mRdMAAHKm82iD2-XTGEaiB5Ol2Hb7aYVA7Ag70QkRwlXp5xYy64qCOY1mphYvnl81QCwasAdZSrO0bKDGZ4BILYACCwGAU3CJGkbocyD7A90Q5H2KuePaD1V0MF51nJfmK7Ai4VbIOa+u6i5X3aHqsEgng+HrqgADIoEGQ+GK0JtrtXgdjmrztu30qPqt7Q7CAu2CC8pyvOQAHUA2HB9gFEMcwOna9iwPBd+WXfp9wUDd7keX83hwugcTQwYTzUM8UCQiDb1gc4d3fd5P0w798NZRiPhofRpCYcpMFMLB+0vGdUz0BAJknbBojWKhuPNPiBI3IiSKIliBlE7U9gDcIACsIGMYALFE3IJXpI1yEiJgyh5LwfD8ECQigCIoikqlsgNEz8kKYosFwazEU0xiwkC7BtL0gyAH1dQNBcDTITIwv0wyNA8nRTKlCweyYJhMBAIRJmmZR-NyWyiQcsI0jkDJcHcq19AKIoGUyGKZLk3j+OgELCJS3JQhCxLIt1CSpikmTjGCQwsAsICHOokdliE8CRweJTmQIg4PVE3RxKckdgFqipfwG5LQj2xJCE4bLmCgFJzQgB5gBSXQFDkFI4AEBAoEiKAAHdmBGaYOgIIhXve5BPu+zBwkENg4CgOQIFYPqjt0pLEjADFzVAAlOBDW6LQAIgKqSCaga6CewCzzQJmhxoMVhwmmzsSV7RbkMOAJJ3ZlaBTkNb2L-TaDW2sIzv8+LcGO8zkGQIGLtBj6vugcayDAZBMH0aY2DSJH+tRgzEmeqBsDgVgEeAB4eHbZhngM5A8BVtWNYMLBwnepGJZAY7Ei8PITWdbaoG4HKyER81aYm1hjCZ4CWbm11oNg4N4M54TXR55c+agLqNsGYWdtO119v8vXwpOsXget7KkvtrBjFMMBgAUSmyEssmLWJ6JxYS-XkspmXK+qR7awASWICByn0aBHqN-2XRpTMfqe4wUnbLxoBDa3VfV2ltYCPQzbexXvprKz27J5OD4X37l9X4x14Prend3x79+H+GBxIAySGePRm9NqAzw5CQAMhABAHQgA)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One of the possible ways to omit keys is using [`as` clause in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as).

> You can filter out keys by producing `never` via a conditional type

```
type OmitNever<T> = { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends never ? never : K]: T[K] }
```

So here we're replacing keys having `never` value with `never` keys and eventually they are omitted.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gEwgGygXigQwHYigenygQFcBbMkAKCogA8w4AnYKUSKesHBAJROQQAPABV4SVPWARsCAM6xEKAHzooAbypRtUAJbY5wHAGMIALihilqAD6XxKANoBdADRadmOXLjHdmYF04bAsAcgAjFGCAczkROFCoO1CACy8YHBBQ9x09bGNkEiQLTJydADNmCF1o7ABpCBAAfhLcKgBfGnZoLh4MsDVNXMcAa0aLQyZ9aOcLXtl%20QSFM5Q6u8Gh%20gDEqmvrGuVEAUQY%20zAGpGXlOU9l%2010sdpmrahpA5VQwhnUcABSY4AN9FAxiA4OVLCduHdzrMPNoRFCzmA-gCwM4btJZAp1FhvL5-IFgmFIsgYnEEg99IYTOZFBIHpVnns3q08J1ck1IbcEP1UYDnI5QtSjPkIKEMXYRE8Xvt3o5ETy%20f8BUKmbK3hLnPCoBZsBAAG4QJhrdYcADyZF0wAAcobjaJPhooI46nkQY1wZY8ZZXRjLtioPqjUwoFzg8bdVA6rNfTGoJ0qN0oMZngEgtgAILAYBTcIkaSHKwSbO53T5wuYq449oPRXQ3nnKuB%20aNsB1mUsg7N67qdqDdpO4soUt5gsQBQAMiglutdpDQm2u1eB2OSvOHeXco%20qyo%20mkTHKmFMWBzY8r320ugQEzL2Gipv3xqPJ9bCgD11b-Q0OvVe3N4QAFYQMYwAWJeuR5DSYp6uQkRMGUkF4j4fjpsSUARFE94UtkOq5PoBRFHSpR4RUW6shhf61ABwGgQA%20pqOq1jqZCZDRIFgT%20SFXgYoqmBYmZMEwmAgEIkzTMoiGQV4KGEhmYRpHIGS4Lh3F5IRxRYG0uSdImT6Hse0BUduXE6KExnsfRmq3lM96msm-z7o6gwum6wKgl6IixiIfoJma0AiBOrAYI52DAEIqYQGhWZnuW46HAEZYVhODxvoy5EHMoygANwEEQuLXjZ0y5RZQEcUV95JEGcHGrlibGMEhhYBYkXRaOcWFsssXJXIqU8r1UDGW8HyDDqhUYYWwCqWRzLUWVoFhJNoQdEAA)

Comment: @AdamBaranyai btw you could do it directly in your mapped type https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gEwgGygXigQwHYigenygQFcBbMkAKCogA8w4AnYKUSKesHBAJROQQAPABV4SVPWARsCAM6xEKdFlwA+FQG8qUXVACW2OcBwBjCAC4oYpagA+18SgDaAXQA0OvZjly4p-UxgfThsKwByACMUUIBzORE4cKgHcIALHxgcEHDPPQNsU2QSJCtsvL0AM2YIfVjsAGkIEAB+MtwqAF8admguHiywFV4IU2YEIWMmQ1j3TgYefkE1HvBoUyYIIJDsAEFgYGnIkmk5USdkfcP9Y9P56VkFOEiAK1HgOYBRGHuZeXnuLJBnMAGINDQYGwSK5HE4QBQAMig2nyzgACgUoABrZpwSpQb5YBTfdGuX6PZFEvwBbahCLRZBxBJJOaGYxmSyKCRzaqbOqNZrtPCdKAtKAYqzYCAANwgTFcFi8+V0JLRrmc4TZJkKEHCZIcYOcqvV4V5tXqTRyrlcXSAA

Comment: You can make this a generic `OmitType` using: `export type OmitType<T, V> = { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends V ? never : K]: T[K] }` where `T` is the type to modify and `V` is the value-type to omit the keys of. To reproduce `OmitNever` would be `OmitType<T, never>`

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example:

```js
type WithNever = {
    a: string
    b: never
}

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type OmitNever<T> = Pick<T, Values<{
    [Prop in keyof T]: [T[Prop]] extends [never] ? never : Prop
}>>

type Result = OmitNever<WithNever>

const test: OmitNever<WithNever> = {
    a: 'test'
}; // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgOQgNwgJygXigbwCgoSoBDALigGdhM4A7Ac2NICMqH0tCBfQgaEhQAamQA2AVwjUAPABUAfLijyA2gGsIIAPYAzVQF1B4aAHkAtglQZMC5XgAKcAMYaFAGlETpcoqSg1R0wdMChGKC1dA3lDKjV1YNDDQygIAA9gCAYAE2pArltUgH4oQqwoKiSwPkVFE2EAJRlJcWAVS2tuO3gkGyx6whcdBlooLNoqTuB%20noQUbocCVhJKKAByCeB1vgBuKAB6A6gdDUIgA)

`OmitNever` - iterates through each key and checks whether it is `never` or not. If it is `never` leave it as is otherwise replace value type with key name.

Then `Values` obtains union of all produced values. Keep in mind  that we ended up with object where each value is a result of conditional type.

If we have a union with `never` like `"a" | never`, TS will remove `never` and leave only `a`. Because of this, `Values` returns a union of all valid keys.

And a last step, we just use [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) with union of all valid keys

If you are wonder why I have used square brackets here `[T[Prop]] extends [never]` - please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69763621/check-if-object-is-empty-using-typescript-generic/69850582#69850582)

**UPDATE**

```js
// type Test = {
//     [x: string]: never;
//     foreignObject: string | number;
//     manyObject: never;
// }
type Test = MapForeignKeys<expands, foreignKeys>
```

Are you sure that `MapForeignKeys` works as expected ? Because it returns and indexed object where each value expected to be `never`.

Comment: well, this works in the playground, but not in my real world example unfortunately. I have a type, that is creating the never types, (added it to my original question), and when I call your OmitNever type on that type, all of the non-never values are being ommited. I presume it is because how my original type is constructed, but I don't know for sure:|

Comment: I just realized, that the original type is already added to the question, so basically, the solution provided works in the simpler example, but does not work when using it on that type. What I did, was I called the `OmitNever<>` type with the type in the question, as it's generic parameter. This indeed removed all never values from the result, but also removed every other value that had a typing.

Comment: @AdamBaranyai please provide reproducible example of your original code

Comment: I updated the question with a new playground link

Comment: @AdamBaranyai made an update

Comment: MapForeignKeys should return an indexed object, where each property is a property from the `TExpandMap` object type, and each value is either never, if the associated value of the currently iterated(?) property does not extend the provided object structure, or a union of value types otherwise. At least, this is what I expect it to do, and what it does, if I fail to omit the never part. I updated my second playground link, to demonstrate.